# Concatenate Multiple CSVs From Glob With Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, glob

I have read many, many similar answers but all solutions have sadly returned no results.

I am importing many CSV files from a folder using Glob and hoping to combine them into one Pandas Dataframe. However, with my current solution, although the columns are perfect, many duplicate rows (duplicate in terms of Player Name & Team) exist.

My current code is as follows:

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

# Concat Code
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, sorted(glob(f"{Year}*.csv"), key=len)), join='outer', ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

My current output is:

| Player Name | Team | Round 1 | Round 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Player A | Team A | 100 | NaN |
| Player B | Team B | 200 | NaN |
| Player C | Team A | NaN | NaN |
| Player A | Team A | NaN | 110 |
| Player B | Team B | NaN | 210 |
| Player C | Team A | NaN | NaN |

My ideal output:

| Player Name | Team | Round 1 | Round 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Player A | Team A | 100 | 110 |
| Player B | Team B | 200 | 210 |
| Player C | Team A | NaN | NaN |

I have tried using the 'groupby', 'agg', 'merge' instead of 'concat' and setting the index but with no success. I will need to keep the original intended NaN values and distinguish them from 0 for the data application.

Thank you for taking the time to help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best answer but if the NaN are always numerical value, why don't you replace them with "0" then grouBy agg should work.
like so:
`df['DataFrame Column'].fillna(0)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but since the players can score a value of 0, I need to keep 0 and NaN separate.

Comment: In your example, you replace Nan with a integer. Even if the player has scored 0, and the Nan is replaced with 0, it will still be zero when you group it. Or do you want to NOT group the lines when it's not Nan ?

Comment: Ideally, if there is an NaN value in the original CSVs, I want it kept as a NaN. My issue is that the CSVs aren't joining properly, creating unnecessary rows. Unfortunately, that is what is making the code so complex for me and why the solutions I am trying online aren't working. Appreciate you attempting to help me though!